# Deleting drawn line in java graphics

Tags: java, swing, line

I have a list containing lines that I draw on gui. I want to be able to select a line and delete it by clicking on the line. I can select and delete but the issue is the repaint method erase all the drawn lines when I do that. When I start drawing a new line, the lines minus the previously deleted line reappear.

I feel like it might be because of the iterator but I'm not entirely sure. Can anyone help with a workaround for this? Or am I doing it wrong?

[image: Delete line2D]
**Here's my codes:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LinesDemo extends JPanel {

private List<Line2D> linesList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Line2D> lineCollection = new ArrayList<>();
private Line2D line = null;
Point pointStart = null;
Point pointEnd   = null;
// Width and height of rectangular region around mouse
// pointer to use for hit detection on lines
private static final int HIT_BOX_SIZE = 4;

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public LinesDemo() {

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            pointStart = e.getPoint();
            line = new Line2D.Double(e.getPoint(), e.getPoint());
            linesList.add(line);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            pointStart = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            getClickedLine(x, y);
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            pointEnd = e.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            pointEnd = e.getPoint();
            line.setLine(pointStart, pointEnd);
            lineCollection.add(line);
            repaint();
        }
    });
}

private Shape getClickedLine(int x, int y) {

    int boxX = x - HIT_BOX_SIZE / 2;
    int boxY = y - HIT_BOX_SIZE / 2;

    int width = HIT_BOX_SIZE;
    int height = HIT_BOX_SIZE;

    for(Line2D selectedLine:lineCollection) {
        if (selectedLine.intersects(boxX, boxY, width, height)) {
            System.out.println("intersects!");
            removeLine(selectedLine);
            return selectedLine;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void removeLine(Line2D line) {
    Iterator<Line2D> it = lineCollection.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Line2D selectedLine = it.next();
        if(selectedLine.equals(line)) {
            it.remove();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    if(pointStart != null) {
        g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        for(Shape content : lineCollection){
            g2d.draw(content);
        }
        g2d.dispose();

    }
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(300, 300);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Moving and Scaling");
    LinesDemo m = new LinesDemo();
    frame.add(m);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Your code says that the console should print "intersects" for each line that it finds. Do you see that message once (which would mean your redraw code is not sound) or twice (indicating your removal/detection is no good)? After you find out, use more System.println's to zoom in on the problem.

Comment: @Jongware The message is shown once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the lines disappear is that you explicitly suppress their drawing in `paintComponent()`:

```
if (pointStart != null) {
```

`pointStart` has been set to `null` in `mouseReleased`, so none of the lines get drawn. Remove that check, and your code should work as you intended.

As a side note, you should create the GUI in the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 1):

UPD2:

Here is your code fixed. There have been many other problems, like: you've been adding a point into a list everytime the mouse is dragged, etc.
It's far from perfect yet, but enough changes already for you to analyze.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LinesDemo extends JPanel {

private List<Line2D> linesList = new ArrayList<>();
private Line2D line = new Line2D.Double();
Point pointStart = null;
Point pointEnd   = null;
// Width and height of rectangular region around mouse
// pointer to use for hit detection on lines
private static final int HIT_BOX_SIZE = 4;

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public LinesDemo() {

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            pointStart = e.getPoint();
            pointEnd = e.getPoint();
            line = new Line2D.Double(pointStart, pointEnd);
            linesList.add(line);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            line.setLine(pointStart, pointEnd);
            pointStart = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            getClickedLine(x, y);
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            pointEnd = e.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            pointEnd = e.getPoint();
            line.setLine(pointStart, pointEnd);
            repaint();
        }
    });
}

private Shape getClickedLine(int x, int y) {

    int boxX = x - HIT_BOX_SIZE / 2;
    int boxY = y - HIT_BOX_SIZE / 2;

    int width = HIT_BOX_SIZE;
    int height = HIT_BOX_SIZE;

    for(Line2D selectedLine:linesList) {
        if (selectedLine.intersects(boxX, boxY, width, height)) {
            System.out.println("intersects!");
            removeLine(selectedLine);
            return selectedLine;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void removeLine(Line2D line) {
    Iterator<Line2D> it = linesList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Line2D selectedLine = it.next();
        if(selectedLine.equals(line)) {
            it.remove();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    for(Shape content : linesList){
        g2d.draw(content);
    }
    g2d.dispose();
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(300, 300);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Moving and Scaling");
    LinesDemo m = new LinesDemo();
    frame.add(m);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Original:
I can't run your program, but can you try replacing

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Line2D selectedLine = it.next();
    if(selectedLine.equals(line)) {
        it.remove();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

with

```
boolean repaintNeeded = false;
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Line2D selectedLine = it.next();
    if(selectedLine.equals(line)) {
        it.remove();
        repaintNeeded = true;
    }
}
if (repaintNeeded) {
  repaint();
}
```

UPD1:
I was able to run your code.
There are many things to improve actually.
For your question specifically, these 2 things lead to your lines not being drawn:

```
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        pointStart = null;
    }
```

and

```
if(pointStart != null) {
```

So every time mouse is released, your code will not draw anything.

Comment: It's still not working unfortunately. Still the same as before.

Comment: You should modify your if statement in `getClickedLine` function for not including first pressed point:

    `if (selectedLine.intersects(boxX, boxY, width, height) &&     selectedLine.getP2().getX()!=x && selectedLine.getP2().getY()!=y)`